# Piping a file that's being written and discarding the contents?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, io-redirection

A software writes its logs on a file ("tonsOf.log"). Those logs are mostly useless and I process them later on with some pattern matching (line by line). So, for say 1 GB of logs, I end up with 40KB of useful information.

I am wondering is the following is possible:

Without modifying the software, instead of writting the contents to that file, send them to a different software that will do the pattern matching (perhaps `grep`) and discard the raw data (perhaps redirect them to `/dev/null`). The important thing is that the software should still think it is writting the logs to the file (so that it won't throw errors).

Can it be done? Where do I even start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the target log file a named pipe, with your filtering script on the other side.